# Confused about number of cores my CPU has

Tags: cpu, cpu-cores

I'm using Plasma 5 (KDE) and I got this information about my CPU from info center

[image]

However this seems to be in conflict with the information on Intels [web site](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/sku/80807/intel-core-i74790k-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz/specifications.html) for the same CPU

[image]

So do I have 8 cores or 4? What did I misunderstand here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Hyperthreading

[Intel's Hyperthreading](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/gaming/resources/hyper-threading.html) allows for two threads per core. Four cores times two threads gives eight threads. Those hardware threads should not be confused with software threads. The later can theoretically be endless.